# How to make status view highlight and hyperlink links

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, status

I made an android app similair to whatsapp. I have a status mechanism. While displying status it doesnt do hyperlinking. I have tried many ways but every other throws an error. please help

Comment: is your purpose to have an underline below the text? please clarify more what exactly you want?

Comment: @RishabhRitweek yes and when clicked should open the url on the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using java code:**

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.facebook.com'> Facebook </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

// From API level >= 24 onwards Html.fromHtml(String source) is deprecated instead use fromHtml(String, int)
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

**Or in the layout XML file, inside your TextView widget attributes**

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: I will try it after a couple of hours and give you the results. cheers!!

Comment: it should work..